# Game bar welcome pop-up wont dissapear - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

Ever since Microsoft released the new game bar, I have experienced bugs. When booting a game, it shows the whole "press win+g" pop-up but it wont disappear afterwards unless I terminate the process in task manager. I also appear to have 2 game bar apps in task manager.[Screenshot of task manager showing two separate xbox apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeWv9.png). I'm running windows 10 enterprise 1809. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used the shortcut to dismiss the Game Bar? (WinKey+G)?

Comment: Also, do note, you can actually press the key in windows. You do not need to be playing a game. Try turning it on and off in windows, then launch the game and try to turn it off there too.

Comment: And the game bar won't launch anywhere else than in a game (possibly because I shut it down in task manager) @LPChip

Comment: So, I managed to launch the game bar, and when I did, I found a setting of "turn off tips when you start a game" in the settings/general tab. Disabling and re-enabling this has made to whole thing work properly again for some reason.